# Защита сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, безопасность

Здравствуйте! Простой сайт на 3-4 странички, возможна БД, форума нет) Хочется организовать защиту от всяких "букашек и червячков", нежелательных действий и т.д. С чего начать? Что почитать? Где посмотреть (примеры реализации)? Подскажите. Спасибо.

Comment: Сделайте сайт на Wordpress или Wiki. Зачем изучать защиту, если 3-4 страницы?

Comment: Есть холодильник с 10-12 продуктами. Возможен джем. С чего начать выпекание пирога?
Я одних только БД могу вам перечислить с десяток. И в каждой из них ещё под сотню функций. И везде могут быть хэки... Вы лучше изучите то, на чем хотите написать более досконально (помимо обычных доков капайте эти ваши гугли на предмет отдельных статей), после чего напишите свои 4 странички и скиньте в соответствующую тему ачата

Comment: С другой стороны, на кой ляд вообще кому-то может понадобится взламывать сайт состоящий из 3-4 страниц? Что на нем может быть такого ценного? Ну а так вообще про валидацию и санитизацию данных надо почитать.

Comment: @yapycoder, LOL, WTF !? WordPress? Вы шутите? В этой "цэмэске" ежемесячно обнаруживается целый букет разных дырок, которые в свою очередь порождают другие...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. SQL Injection
2. [XSS атаки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)

Answer (score 2):

1. Если боитесь SQL Injection - используйте PDO + prepare.
2. Следите за include если подключаемый фал ззависит от действий пользователя. Проще всего обезопасить себя через использование оператора switch
3. Все входящие данные преобрауйте в спецсимволы перд записью в базу и после вывода из базы для полной паранои :).
4. Не парьтесь. Лучшая защита это резервная копия. Если вас не взломали, значит вами не занимались.